# Filter by nested property in web api odata

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have some issues in Odata filter with nested property,

Controller:

```
[HTTPGet]
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IQueryable<MyObj>> GetData()
{
    return await GetUserData();
}
```

Output from web app for the get url request,

```
GET https://sample.com/IB

[{
        "Id": "1",
        "FirstName": "Alex",
        "School": [
            {
                "SchoolId": "Sc1",
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Role": "ROOT",
                    }
                ],
                "Email": "abc@xyz.com"
            }
        ]
    },    
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "FirstName": "Mage",
        "School": [
            {
                "SchoolId": "Sc2",
                "Roles": [
                    {
                        "Role": "Admin",
                    }
                ],
                "Email": "abc@xyz.com"
            }
        ]
    }]
```

How to get the results of school, where SchoolId =  "Sc2"

I have tried with below url,

```
GET https://sample.com/IB?$expand=School&$filter=School/SchoolId eq 'Sc2'
```

but I got the below error message,

```
{
    "Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. The parent value for a property access of a property 'SchoolId' is not a single value. Property access can only be applied to a single value."
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, but you need to go after the collection with the lambda `any` operator.

```
https://sample.com/IB?$expand=School&$filter=School/Any (c:c/SchoolId eq 'Sc2')
```